# Is there a TypeScript way of getting a child from a state in xState?

Tags: typescript, xstate

At the moment I do it like this:

`useActor<SomeInterpreter>((state as any).children.SomeChild);`

Since I'm not a big fan of "any" in TypeScript, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: `useActor` should be able to infer the type automatically based on the input arguments. Since you used `state as any`, this is not possible. So, what are you trying to accomplish in the first place? (https://xyproblem.info/)
Also, could you provide more context on what kind of state object you are passing? If you would create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project on a platform like Codesandbox, it would be easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of this comment this is not possible, according to David Khourshid. they will add a better way in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).